# What to do with a late answer which is identicall to the accepted asnwer?

Tags: discussion, answers

I am new to review system and in general I find it difficult to make the right choice.

I came up to a situation where a new user post his/her first answer. The answer was identical to the accepted answer five year ago.

The question and answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/257476/40948

What should I do? I don't think I can down-vote because is the right answer but on the other hand there is no point to answer a question after 5 years that has been already answered.

Also this answer on the same topic

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/257475/40948

I don't think is a good answer. Imo is bad coding. What should I do? Down-voted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular case the new answer is one line of code without explanation and deserves a downvote for lack of quality.

More in general, duplicate answers are sometimes a nuisance, but don't disturb the system as duplicate questions do (because we want the best answers to a question concentrated in one place).

However, there are reasons to review duplicate answers carefully. They may just be there because of the poster's laziness or ignorance. But they may also be a sign of abuse, such as hiding a spam-link or building up reputation for a network of trolls.

Answer (score 5):

If an answer, as in this case, doesn't add anything new, flag it, and we will delete it. I just did that.

Sometimes, there is something new or different in these answers, then we might leave it. Not in this case.